# What word(s) am I?

Tags: riddle

I'm a 7-letter word. As a phrasal verb, I mean: 'begin to operate'.

And if you read me palindromically, (contains multi-words e.g like crosswords does) I mean: keep mices? (3-4).

Let's see who'll crack this word.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are:

> **START UP**

Backwards, you are:

> **PUT RATS**